# Rails secure with hidden field and firebug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a web application and what is bothering me is the fact that users can use firebug to manipulate the code.

```
<%= form_for([@journal, @news]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <%= f.hidden_field :journal %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :journal do 
  resources: news
end
```

The url appears like so mysite.com/journal/1/news/3. Since the journal id is in the url how can I prevent a user from changing journal id value of 1 to something like 2 or 3.

```
<input id="news_journal_id" type="hidden" value="1" name="news[journal_id]">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. NEVER trust input from anywhere. Implement a server-side validation/role-model/access-limitation of any kind.

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent users from sending you modified input. You can (and should) check that input on the server instead of blindly accepting it.

If a user can't read/write this journal, redirect him to a corresponding page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use current_user associations to fetch any record, to make your application secure.

For example:

```
journal = currect_user.journals.find(params[:news][:journal_id])
journal.news.create(params[:news].except(:journal_id))
```